# A minute rate time series graph using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have got a file which looks like this

```
Times   Code505 Code200 Code404
1543714067  855 86123   1840
1543714077  869 87327   1857
1543714087  882 88522   1883
1543714097  890 89764   1901
1543714107  904 90735   1924
1543714117  914 91963   1956
```

except it got a lot more data than this.
What I want to do is to plot a graph that looks like this [image]

When I plot my graph, I get something more of this

[image]

What I am doing to get my graph which is the second one is

```
  data['Times'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Times'], unit = 's')
  data.set_index(['Times'],inplace=True)
  data.plot()
```

I know I am missing something to get my graph look like a time series but I am unsure what I have to pass to pandas to get my graph look right.

I am collecting the data for a total of an hour and I collect a record which looks like this

```
  1543714067    855 86123   1840
```

every 10 seconds

Comment: You are plotting the actual data. Looks like your desired graph is plotting some type of rate based on differences between time periods.  What does `RPS(1-minute rate)` mean?

Comment: @wwii The 1-minute rate is the difference between the values at tnow and t60-seconds-ago divided by 60 seconds to get a Request Per Second (RPS) rate. Thats how the RPS was defined by the requirement

Comment: So you need to calculate the RPS for every sixty second period and plot those values instead.

Comment: @wwii So will create a pd dataframe columns that contains the calculated RPS for each column and plot it against the time on the x axis?

Comment: Or create a new DataFrame - you should realize that the last five values in each Series will be NaN because there are not enough subsequent data points to get sixty seconds.

Comment: @wwii I am sorry, I am struggling to understand you. When you say create a new DataFrame, you mean I should use my raw data to create a new data frame which has the RPS already?

Comment: Is your data the total requests for each (10 second) time period? Or does each row represents the number of requests since *t0*?

Comment: @wwii I am requesting data from a time server which is obviously adding to time so if say I start at time 1543714067 I record that data and the number of 404, 200, and 500 code on the stats page of the time server. Then 10 seconds later, the time server would have moved to 1543714077 and record data again. So I am recording data 10 seconds from each time period

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> df
        Times  Code505  Code200  Code404
0  1543714067      855    86123     1840
1  1543714077      869    87327     1857
2  1543714087      882    88522     1883
3  1543714097      890    89764     1901
4  1543714107      904    90735     1924
5  1543714117      914    91963     1956
>>>
```

This will calculate the RPS based on twenty second intervals:

Shift the data *up* 2 and subtract the original DataFrame

```
>>> df.shift(-2)
          Times  Code505  Code200  Code404
0  1.543714e+09    882.0  88522.0   1883.0
1  1.543714e+09    890.0  89764.0   1901.0
2  1.543714e+09    904.0  90735.0   1924.0
3  1.543714e+09    914.0  91963.0   1956.0
4           NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
5           NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
>>> 
>>> deltas = df.shift(-2) - df
>>> deltas
   Times  Code505  Code200  Code404
0   20.0     27.0   2399.0     43.0
1   20.0     21.0   2437.0     44.0
2   20.0     22.0   2213.0     41.0
3   20.0     24.0   2199.0     55.0
4    NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
5    NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
>>>
```

Divide the deltas by twenty, then reestablish the times.

```
>>> rates = deltas / 20
>>> rates
   Times  Code505  Code200  Code404
0    1.0     1.35   119.95     2.15
1    1.0     1.05   121.85     2.20
2    1.0     1.10   110.65     2.05
3    1.0     1.20   109.95     2.75
4    NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
5    NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
>>> rates['Times'] = df['Times']
>>> rates
        Times  Code505  Code200  Code404
0  1543714067     1.35   119.95     2.15
1  1543714077     1.05   121.85     2.20
2  1543714087     1.10   110.65     2.05
3  1543714097     1.20   109.95     2.75
4  1543714107      NaN      NaN      NaN
5  1543714117      NaN      NaN      NaN
>>>
```

---

You can preserve the timestamps throughout the process if you make it the index first.

```
>>> df
        Times  Code505  Code200  Code404
0  1543714067      855    86123     1840
1  1543714077      869    87327     1857
2  1543714087      882    88522     1883
3  1543714097      890    89764     1901
4  1543714107      904    90735     1924
5  1543714117      914    91963     1956
>>> df = df.set_index('Times')
>>> df
            Code505  Code200  Code404
Times                                
1543714067      855    86123     1840
1543714077      869    87327     1857
1543714087      882    88522     1883
1543714097      890    89764     1901
1543714107      904    90735     1924
1543714117      914    91963     1956
>>> 
>>> deltas = df.shift(-2) - df
>>> rates = deltas / 20
>>> rates
            Code505  Code200  Code404
Times                                
1543714067     1.35   119.95     2.15
1543714077     1.05   121.85     2.20
1543714087     1.10   110.65     2.05
1543714097     1.20   109.95     2.75
1543714107      NaN      NaN      NaN
1543714117      NaN      NaN      NaN
>>>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted! Thanks @wwii